# While с двумя условиями в Python

Tags: python, while

Используя цикл, запрашивайте у пользователя число, пока оно не станет больше 0, но меньше 10.
После того, как пользователь введет корректное число, возведите его в степень 2 и выведите на экран.

```py
while True:
    number = int(input("Введите число от 0 до 10 "))
    if number  < 0 and number > 10:
        print('Число должно быть от 0 до 10')
    else:
        break

print(number,'во второй степени равно', number**2)
```

Выходит из цикла при любом варианте. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог(галочка около ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте or, а не and(ведь число не может быть одновременно больше 10 и меньше 0):

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Введите число от 0 до 10 "))
    if number  < 0 or number > 10:
        print('Число должно быть от 0 до 10')
    else:
        break

print(number,'во второй степени равно', number**2)
```

Comment: @Ильнур Не надо писать спасибо, вместо этого примите ответ (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
if number<10 and  number>0:
```

Comment: Это совсем наоборот, придется переделывать остальное.

Answer (score 1):

Более короткая запись:

```
if not (0 < number < 10):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Введите число от 0 до 10 "))
    if number  < 0 or number > 10:
        print('Число должно быть от 0 до 10')
    else:
        break

print(number,'во второй степени равно', number**2)
```

Просто поменяйте `and` на `or`